# How do I correctly use Or with strings in an if statement

Tags: python

This is a function I wrote. If I enter Wednesday as the day of the week, the program can't get to it to execute the print code. What is the correct syntax for that line of code to make Wednesday work correctly?

```
def day(dayOfWeek):
    if dayOfWeek == ("Monday" or "Wednesday"):
        print("Poetry: 6-7:15 in Chem 131")
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The expression `("Monday" or "Wednesday")` in your code is always evaluated to `"Monday"`.  The operator `or` is a logical `or` that first tries if its first operand [evaluates to `True`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing).  If yes, it returns the first operand, otherwise it returns the second operand.  Since `"Monday"` is "trucy", your comparison always compares with `"Monday"`.

Use this instead:

```
if dayOfWeek in ("Monday", "Wednesday"):
    print("Poetry: 6-7:15 in Chem 131")
```

Comment: so "in" before and a comma in there?

Comment: @Zack Shapiro: `("Monday", "Wednesday")` is just a tuple. It is generated "on the fly". `in` is used to test whether an element is in a list, tuple or dict. No magic.

Answer (score 3):

The answer given by **Sven** will work, and is probably the best method, but just to demonstrate how to properly use `or`, you have to do it like this:

```
if (dayOfWeek == "Monday") or (dayOfWeek == "Wednesday"):
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `==`

```
if dayOfWeek == "Monday" or dayOfWeek == "Wednesday":
    print("Poetry: 6-7:15 in Chem 131")
```